# Share data without database

Tags: javascript, concurrency, frontend, shared-data

I have this web application that gets and displays data from SAP, but i need a way (maybe a JSON file?) to share some data between different users, with the possibility to modify these same data for each user (even at the same time), without a database. There will be really small data and few users, and what i would write is simple data that tells me who is online in that moment. How can i do? I'd like to know if exist an easy solution to share these really small and simple data. I'm using React with no back, because i'm taking all the data i need from SAP. Clearly, i'm a beginner. All advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talking about some prototype like MVPs, I think JSON files would be best.
However, consider to work also that you can work with Local Storage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I ended up using SAP db also for these data, but otherwise i'm sure JSON would have been the better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), SessionStorage or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), but the last option is an in-browser database. Maybe LocalStorage is your solution.